# Case insensitive correction of input strings in R/exams in OpenOLAT

Tags: r, r-exams

This question concerns online exams in OpenOLAT, written with the R/exams function `exams2openolat()`. I'm asking a question as outlined below (with 4 different versions) where students have to enter a sequence of letters, e.g., `J`, `F`, `I`, ...

Is there a way to have the input processed case insensitively, so that both upper-case letters (as above) and lower-case letters (i.e., `j`, `f`, `i`, ...) are accepted as correct?

```
i = sample(1:4, 1)

question = concat("...")
correct = c("J,F,I,B,Z,M,L,X,A,C,Q", "N,T,E,Y,Z,H,M,L,A,C,Q", "A,T,L,R,Z,V,C,E,H,M,Q", "P,I,W,J,Z,D,Q,X,E,S,M")
...
answertypes = paste(replicate(11, "string"), collapse = "|")
answerlist = sprintf("%s:",seq(1,11))
exsolution = gsub(",", "\\|", correct[i])
solutionlist = strsplit(gsub(",", "", correct[i]), "")[[1]]
```

Comment: convert both to same case before testing. using e.g. `tolower`

Comment: Which package is `concat` function from?

Comment: There wasn't such an option up to now but I have just added it to the source code. I'll wait until the package is rebuilt on R-Forge and then write a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion. This option is available in OpenOlat and in the QTI 2.1 XML format that is used for exchange - however, up to now it was not supported by `exams2openolat()` and the underlying `exams2qti21()` function. I have added this now to version 2.4-0 of R/exams. So now you can do

```
exams2openolat(..., casesensitive = FALSE)
```

The default continues to be `TRUE`. As a worked example you can consider

```
exams2openolat(expar("function.Rmd", i = 8), casesensitive = FALSE)
```

This picks one of the eight available random versions of the [function](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/function/) exercise which has the correct answer `logLik` (note the capital L in the middle). With the option `casesensitive = FALSE` any other case including `loglik`, `LOGLIK`, or `LoGlIk` is accepted as correct as well.

Comment: Wow, many, many thanks from Innsbruck to Innsbruck!

Comment: You're very welcome. Feel free to get in touch directly with me or in the "Distance Learning" OLAT course (see the links at the bottom of https://www.uibk.ac.at/ecampus/werkzeuge/rexams.html.de). It's always good to hear from the local user community :-)